# Using an R function on a column

Tags: r, data.table

I wish to use a function on a number of columns in a dataframe:

```
library(data.table)
id <- seq(1:1000)
region <- rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"),c(200,200,200,200,200))
treatment.1 <- sample(0:1, 1000, replace=T)
treatment.2 <- sample(0:1, 1000, replace=T)
d <- data.frame(id,region,treatment.1,treatment.2)
```

I wish to create a function which allows me to calculate the proportion of 1s by region (in different treatment groups).  So far I have been using the following code:

```
setDT(d)[,.(.N,prop=sum(treatment.1==1)/.N),
         by=region]
```

However, when I try and turn the code into a function, I am having some problems (the answer does not match what I previously got without the function):

```
treatment.pc <- function (x) {
  setDT(d)[,.(.N,prop=sum(x==1)/.N),
           by=region]
}

treatment.pc (d$treatment.1)
treatment.pc (d$treatment.2)
```

What do I need to do to the code to make it work?

Comment: "some problems" , aha. So, you need some solution for some problems. A bit vague ...

Comment: I think the problem is that you just pass one vector to your function. However, your function also expects a `region`.  So I would guess you have to pass a data.frame to your function with one variable called `region`.

Comment: When you passing your function `d$treatment.1`, data.table can't tell it's part of its own variables, it's just sees a binary vector. So it just does `d[, sum(d$treatment.1)/.N, by = region]` instead of `d[, sum(treatment.1)/.N, by = region]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setDT(d)

fun <- function (x) {
  prob = mean(x==1L)
}

d[, c(lapply(.SD, fun), N = .N), by = region, .SDcols = c("treatment.1", "treatment.2")]
```

It's unclear to me if you need to wrap the last line into a function ...

```
fun2 <- function(DT, fun, cols) {
  setDT(DT)
  DT[, c(lapply(.SD, fun), N = .N), by = region, .SDcols = cols]
}

fun2(d, fun, c("treatment.1", "treatment.2"))
```

Comment: You could just do `d[, c(lapply(.SD, mean), .N), by = region, .SDcols = c("treatment.1", "treatment.2")]` in this case. Maybe also worth adding what was OPs error too.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a simpler solution for your problem using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

id <- seq(1:1000)
region <- rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"),c(200,200,200,200,200))
treatment.1 <- sample(0:1, 1000, replace=T)
treatment.2 <- sample(0:1, 1000, replace=T)
d <- data.frame(id,region,treatment.1,treatment.2)

by_col <- d %>% group_by(region) %>% summarise_each(funs(k = mean))
```

With only one line code you get the result I think you want and you don't have to write a function.

Comment: How is this simpler or less code than `setDT(d)[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = region]` ?

Comment: Haven't seen this solution yet. At least for me `dplyr` is more intuitive than `data.table`. But this might depend on the point of view.

Comment: OP is asking a data.table question.

Comment: He states his problem and then says: " So far I have been using the following code:". But `data.table` is only one way to solve it.